# Is it possible to send real-time data to microsoft-cognitive Speaker Recognition?

Tags: python, azure-cognitive-services

I am writing an application which should receive audio and send it to Speaker Recognition API to get text. I used the Service Library and it works with a wav file. So I wrote my own stream to receive audio from mic or network (RTP) as send it to the recognition API. When I add a WAV header in front of the audio stream, it works for some seconds.

Debugging shows, that the recognition api reads form stream faster than it is filled by audio source (16k samplerate, 16 bit, mono).

So my question is: Is there a way to use the recognize api with a real-time (continuous) audio stream?

I know there is an example with a microphone client, but it works with microphone only and I need it for different sources

Comment: Do you mean **Speech** Recognition (as opposed to **Speaker**)?  I ask because you say 'to get text'.  If the former, please fix the text and then add the speech-recognition tag; if the latter, you might add the voice-recognition tag.